# with metal why +Y = up in clip coordinates (and NDC) but +Y = down in framebuffer coordinates?

Tags: metal, metalkit

In [this](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2019/04/keeping-blue-side-up-coordinate.html) article it says:

> Metal's convention is to have +Y = up in clip coordinates (and NDC)
>   but +Y = down in framebuffer coordinates, with the framebuffer origin
>   in the upper left.

What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> What does this mean exactly?

This means that Y axis direction is relative to the origin.

**NDC:** +Y is up. Point(-1, -1) is at the bottom left corner.
**Framebuffer coordinate:** +Y is down. Origin(0, 0) is at the top left corner.
**Texture coordinate:** +Y is down. Origin(0, 0) is at the top left corner.

---

**1) NDC (Normalized Device Coordinate):** this coordinates is used by developers to construct their geometries and transform the geometries in vertex shader via model and view matrices.
**Point(-1, -1)** in **NDC** is located at the **the bottom left corner (Y up).**.
[image]

---

**2) Framebuffer Coordinate (Viewport coordinate):** when we write into attachment or read from attachment or copy/blit between attachments, we use framebuffer coordiante to specify the location. The **origin(0, 0)** is located at the **top-left corner (Y down)**.
[image]

---